# Rework sed for vim's errorformat for circom compiler

Tags: sed, vim

compiling ciruits and intend to use quickfix. but the compiler output was not in standard format ... so tried parsing

Need help

1. fixing the sed command
2. preping the output for error format so that i can use the quikfix window

Issue

1. the circom compiler outputs a bunch of ascii code for colors. parsed by the terminal but

```
[0m[1m[38;5;9merror[P1000][0m[1m: UnrecognizedToken { token: (374, Token(60, "input"), 379), expected: ["\"!=\"", "\"%\"", "\"%=\"", "\"&\"", "\"&&\"", "\"&=\"", "\"(\"", "\")\"", "\"*\"", "\"**\"", "\"**=\"", "\"*=\"", "\"+\"", "\"++\"", "\"+=\"", "\",\"", "\"-\"", "\"--\"", "\"-->\"", "\"-=\"", "\".\"", "\"/\"", "\"/=\"", "\":\"", "\";\"", "\"<\"", "\"<--\"", "\"<<\"", "\"<<=\"", "\"<=\"", "\"<==\"", "\"=\"", "\"==\"", "\"===\"", "\"==>\"", "\">\"", "\">=\"", "\">>\"", "\">>=\"", "\"?\"", "\"[\"", "\"\\\\\"", "\"\\\\=\"", "\"]\"", "\"^\"", "\"^=\"", "\"|\"", "\"|=\"", "\"||\""] }[0m
   [0m[34m┌─[0m "merkleTreeUpdater.circom":10:13
   [0m[34m│[0m
[0m[34m10[0m [0m[34m│[0m     ssignal [0m[31minput[0m oldRoot;
   [0m[34m│[0m             [0m[31m^^^^^[0m [0m[31mInvalid syntax[0m

[31mprevious errors were found[0m
```

i am unable to parse correctly

```
error[P1000]: UnrecognizedToken { token: (374, Token(60, "input"), 379), expected: ["\"!=\"", "\"%\"", "\"%=\"", "\"&\"", "\"&&\"", "\"&=\"", "\"(\"", "\")\"", "\"*\"", "\"**\"", "\"**=\"", "\"*=\"", "\"+\"", "\"++\"", "\"+=\"", "\",\"", "\"-\"", "\"--\"", "\"-->\"", "\"-=\"", "\".\"", "\"/\"", "\"/=\"", "\":\"", "\";\"", "\"<\"", "\"<--\"", "\"<<\"", "\"<<=\"", "\"<=\"", "\"<==\"", "\"=\"", "\"==\"", "\"===\"", "\"==>\"", "\">\"", "\">=\"", "\">>\"", "\">>=\"", "\"?\"", "\"[\"", "\"\\\\\"", "\"\\\\=\"", "\"]\"",
"\"^\"", "\"^=\"", "\"|\"", "\"|=\"", "\"||\""] }
   ┌─ "merkleTreeUpdater.circom":10:13
   │
10 │     ssignal input oldRoot;
   │             ^^^^^ Invalid syntax

previous errors were found
```

tried parsing it for `errorformat`

```
circom merkleTreeUpdater.circom &> >( tr -d '\n' | (sed 's/\x1B[@A-Z\\\]^_]\|\x1B\[[0-9:;<=>?]*[-!"#$%&'"'"'()*+,.\/]*[][\\@A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]//g') | (sed "s/{.*}//g") | (sed 's/\s*//g')| sed 's/^.*\]\://g' | sed 's/\(^.*\:\).*/\1/g' | sed 's/"//g' | tr -s '[\200-\377]' :)
```

ouputs:

```
UnrecognizedToken:merkleTreeUpdater.circom:10:
```

i can set the error format but have issues feeding into `makeprg` and nvim quits

Comment: Don't you have a compiler option to produce non-color output? It's usually better to fix the cause of the problem rather than working around the symptoms.

Comment: i am not sure how that addresses the problem. the compiler is pushing color encoded data, errorformat will definitely need it parsed